# is it possible to make one sql query to select a row and all associated rows from relations to two other tables

Tags: sql

I have a `lists` table, a `users` table and an `items` table.

There is also a `users_to_lists` join table and an `items_to_lists` join table.

I would like to, in one SQL query, select all of a particular user's lists and also all of those lists users and items.

To select the lists, I use the following SQL query:

```
SELECT lists.*
  FROM lists
 INNER JOIN users_to_lists ON lists.list_id = users_to_lists.list_id
 WHERE users_to_lists.user_id = 'some_user_id'
```

This works fine and I can get all of the lists for that particular user.  However in the same query I would like to also select all of the items in each list and all of the users in each list.  Is this possible in one statement?

Edit

The desired output is:

```
{List1, User1, User2, User3, Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4}
{List2, User2, User3, User8, Item1, Item6, Item13, Item24, Item88}
```

I'm not at all concerned with ordering.  Just need to retrieve each List that a user has and all of the users and items for that particular list so that I may add them to a local database which will handle all of the sorting.

Comment: Please identify your DBMS — and add the appropriate tag to the question.  Also, please provide outline schema and matching sample data for the 5 tables, and show the desired result.

Comment: It depends on what you want as the result.  Suppose that for a particular entry in `lists` there are 3 entries in `users_to_lists` that match, and 2 entries in `items_to_lists`.  How many rows of output do you want?  Getting 6 is easy (outer joins).  Any other number is harder — you have to define how you want things ordered, and then have to work hard to get the result (which, I'm guessing, is 3 rows — one for each user entry, with one distinct matching row for each item entry, and one row with no data shown (NULL) for the user entry without a distinct item).

Comment: I'm guessing your desired output is (1) `{ List1, User1, Item1 }`, `{ List1, User2, Item2 }`, `{ List1, User3, NULL }` — so looking down the users column, you see the three users associated with `List1`, and looking down the items column, you see the 2 items associated with `List1`.

Comment: thank you.  I have edited the question to show the desired output.  I want an array of outputs that are the list and all it's users and items so that I can add them to my local database.  Not concerned at all with the ordering as the local database will handle all of that.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to achieve what you show.  All else apart, there's no formal way to distinguish between the user columns and the item columns.  In some DBMS, you could get a row type similar to `ROW(ListID INT, LIST{User1, User2, User3}::VARCHAR(10), LIST{Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4}::INT)` where the types are fungible to suit your situation — you'd have three elements in the row, a List ID, a list of Users, and a list of Items.  But as shown at the moment, you're looking at something non-relational and ambiguous (both of which are bad news).   _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ We can debate how relational lists are (and you should probably use SET instead of LIST, come to think of it), but at least it is unambiguous.  Again, you need to identify the DBMS.

Comment: understand.  thanks for your comments.  I will rethink my approach.  I'm mainly a front end developer and not a great deal of experience with sql and backends although have been using it for a while for simpler operations.  thanks.

Comment: I think a rethink is sensible.  Much the simplest method (with the least rethinking) will be two queries, one for the users, one for the items — they'll just happen to have the same User ID as the key data in the queries.  You can then deal with the two sets of data appropriately.  Most of the alternatives are harder work.

Comment: I am using that approach in other places where a specific list is retrieved.  "The problem is when I want to retrieve all of the lists and all of there associated items and users at the same time.  The use case is a background refresh for a mobile app.  The app is a todo list that can be shared amongst users.  Each user can have multiple lists and each list will have multiple users and items.  The backend is an sql database with join tables for the many to many relations of users to lists and items to lists.  I didn't want to store sets of item_id's because there could be thousands in a list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179343/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-alionthego).